# Sorting by votes: Isn't logical that accepted answers rank higher than non-accepts?

Tags: feature-request, sorting

When running a sort on votes on my profile it appears that the sort order is:

1. Number of votes (descending)
2. Question ask time (descending)

I think it is more logical that accepted answers out-rank non-accepts in terms of usefulness, i.e.

1. Number of votes (descending)
2. Accept then Non-Accept
3. Question ask time (descending)

[image]

Comment: +1 Yes, it can be a useful feature, specially when I am looking for a particular answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accepts are what the asker thinks of your question. Votes are what the community feels. A few things:

- <s>The asker may not revisit the site. After the question is answered+accepted, someone may write an awesome answer that gets lots of votes.</s>
- The asker is usually not someone who you would trust to know the best answer, since the asker is confused in that field anyways. On the other hand, your community is diverse and more reliable for choosing the right answer. Usually.

Comment: On your second point: One of the best features of Stack Overflow is that contributions from both Askers and Experts are rewarded - by Experts and Askers. The Asker is the best placed person to know if their question has been solved, even if *some* of the finer detail or techniques in *some* answers on *some* occasions may be better appreciated in a technical sense by other experts. On your first point, my proposal does not elevate accepts over votes

Comment: @brettdj hmm.. Maybe its like that on SO, but at least on physics.SE, the asker is not the one who would know the correct answer. Regarding the first point--Sorry about that, removed.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question: No it isn't logical because accepts are not votes.

Votes are used to order the answers according to the community. Accepts are only for the question asker.

I can imagine that there is a wish for an additional view that orders answers on their value to the asker—one where only accepted answers are shown. But there are lots of ways answers can be ordered, and there is no need to implement them all.